# Redux is run first

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-redux

I am using redux to manage the global state of my app.

I have the global state "shop" and change its value through "onFilterShops".

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ shops }) => {
    return {
        shops: shops.shops
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onFilterShops: shop => dispatch(filterShops(shop))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MenuShop)
```

Changing this state runs a filter in my app and takes a few seconds, so I want to display a Spinner during this process.

```
const toggleMenu = index => {
        setIsLoading(true) //Local state, Spinner visible - Line 1
        props.onFilterShops(index) // Line 2
        setIsLoading(false) //Local state, Spinner invisible - Line 3
    }
```

The problem is that first line 2 is executed, the filter is done and at the end of the filter, line 1 and line 3 are executed and the Spinner has no chance of appearing.

If I put a promise in the middle it works, but it's ugly.

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
const toggleMenu = async (index) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        await wait(1)
        props.onFilterShops(index)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }
```

Why?

Comment: If promises are ugly than don't use javascript. There are alterntives: Kotlin/JS with React for example. Here you can use courutines. They are very pritty and expressive. And which porpouse has the 1 second delay here?

Comment: Hi @BierDav. It's not the promises that are ugly, it's what I did. I created a promise that waits 1 millisecond before executing the filter. This is ugly, it must have a more elegant way.

Comment: That makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can think of dispatching actions as "triggering an event" in the application.

Your function execution on line 2 will merely dispatch the action, thus it will not wait for the code to have run.

For this reason line 3 is fired immediately and it will seem like your loading spinner never appeared.

There are several ways to achieve the functionality you want, for example through [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), assuming the code is asynchronous.

I think a good starting point would be to learn the redux fundamentals.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: I don't have any asynchronous processes. I just set a local state (setIsLoading) to display the Spinner, change the Global state (props.onFilterShops) and set the local state again (setIsLoading) to disappear with Spinner.

Comment: If there's no asynchronous logic, maybe you don't need a loading spinner? If you're setting global state to a local list/variable, you wouldn't even see the state change because of how fast it happens.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with redux. I simplified my question into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627714/show-spinner-before-filters-object

Comment: When I change the global state, my UI is rendered, and various components render based on that global state, it takes time, so I need an Indicator @Robin Claes

Answer (score -1):

**The Problem**

In line 1 you scheduled updateing the state, but immediately after that you are blocking the whole thread so redux has no chance to update the ui until the heavy load is over. And when the load is over you have already set the state back to its original state.

**The Solution**

According to this thread, you have to dispatch the setIsLoading function: [React Loading Spinner + Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778392/react-loading-spinner-redux)

Have also a look on promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Simple usage:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
let computationResult = "Hello World!"

function someLoadingFunction(){
   dispatch(setIsLoading(true))
   new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      //Do your filtering
      return "this result took really long and baked your cpu"
   }.then((result) => {
      computationResult = result
      dispatch(setIsLoading(false))
   }
   
}

someLoadingFunction()
console.log(computationResult)
```

I hope you understand ;)

If it helped: Mark my answer as answered. At the moment I want to get some more reputation ;)

If there are any questions left: just comment

Comment: Hi @BierDav, 
I'm implementing your help, I'll answer you . thx

Comment: It didn't work, Spinner doesn't exit and only runs after the filter finishes.

Comment: const toggleMenu = index => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            props.onFilterShops(index)
            return "this result took really long and baked your cpu"
        })
            .then(result => {
                setIsLoading(false)
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }

Comment: Wait let me see

Comment: I can't evaluate the problem. May you give me a fully example I can run?

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/yNF1lSTa#OAZ5VbSxnDjH3InA734VzYBWIWT9zODKYS5RlNG_POw

Comment: setIsLoading(true)
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            props.onFilterShops(index)
            resolve()
        })
            .then(_ => {
                setIsLoading(false)
            }) -------------------So it keeps running isLoading(true) and (false) only at the end

Comment: ok. that's wierd. What does your "filterShops" function do?

Comment: Sends an action creator (https://mega.nz/file/ecVGhJ7R#l3SuH18YIw0zCrmUclUG4n_FjCeSFIhrcSvXv7IsDnU) and changes the global shop status data (https://mega.nz/file/DQ8z3aoQ#J008ERBJEWNAy3OCCrLcwk5Z8ZiIK52Vja_GEwFOd8Q).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help much. Nevertheless I have found something: Try dispach the setIsLoading function. I have already updated my answer. But even though it would work without Promises I recommend using them because so you can be 100% sure that you are not blocking anything

Comment: If you can look there

Comment: Please edit your question and don't create a new one

Comment: No it doesn't simplify. It causes duplicates and unanswered questions. Please delete the new question and copy the content of it in here. This is what the edit button is for.